# WooCommerce checkout - Update Shipping cost

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Sendy API to calculate the shipping cost in my checkout page based on the location one chooses from the dropdown managed by Google Location API.
everything else works fine except for my shipping which is not being calculated. I am not sure how to pass the shipping since I keep getting 0 value every time I select a location. After googling, I came up with this code breakdown. Someone, please help how to achieve that.

1. AJAX pulling shipping cost from the API

   ```
   function sendy_api_script() 
   {
   ?>
   <?php if(is_checkout()){ ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
       $('#sendy_location').niceSelect('destroy');

       $(document).on('change','#sendy_location',function(){
           shipping_location_selected = $(this).val();
           cart_total = $('.cart-subtotal .woocommerce-Price-amount').text().replace("KShs","");
            $.post(ajaxurl,{
                "action": 'update_shipping_cost',
                "sendy_location":shipping_location_selected,
                "cart_total":cart_total,
            },function(){
                $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
            });
       });

       var input = document.getElementById('sendy_location');
       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', input); 

       var options = {
           types: ['geocode'],
           componentRestrictions: {country: "ke"}
       };

       var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

       google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
           var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
           document.getElementById('city2').value = place.name;
           document.getElementById('cityLat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
           document.getElementById('cityLng').value = place.geometry.location.lng();

           //sendy api call
           var name = $('#billing_first_name').val()+' '+$('#billing_last_name').val();
           var phone = $('#billing_phone').val();
           var email = $('#billing_email').val();
           var customerLocation = $('#city2').val();
           var cityLat = $('#cityLat').val();
           var cityLng = $('#cityLng').val();
           var amountTotal = $('#amounttotal').val();
           var pickupdate = $('#pickupdate').val();
           var requestToken = $('#randomvalue').val();

           /* distance calculation between customer pickup point and Kericho Gold dispatch location */
           var dispatchNairobi = 'Nairobi, Kenya';
           var dispatchMombasa = 'Mombasa, Kenya';

           // var source = 'Nairobi, Kenya';
           var destination = customerLocation;

           var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
           service.getDistanceMatrix({
               origins: [dispatchNairobi],
               destinations: [destination],
               travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
               unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
               avoidHighways: false,
               avoidTolls: false
           }, function (response, status) {
               if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                   var distanceNairobi = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
                   var durationNairobi = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;

                   $("#nairobiDistance").val(distanceNairobi).change();

               } else {
                   alert("An error occured.");
               }
           });

           service.getDistanceMatrix({
               origins: [dispatchMombasa],
               destinations: [destination],
               travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
               unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
               avoidHighways: false,
               avoidTolls: false
           }, function (response, status) {
               if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                   var distanceMombasa = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
                   var durationMombasa = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;

                   $("#mombasaDistance").val(distanceMombasa).change();

               } else {
                   alert("An error occured.");
               }
           });             

           /* end */
           jQuery('input#mombasaDistance').on( 'change', function(){
               if( $("#mombasaDistance").val() < $("#nairobiDistance").val() )
               {
                   var dispatchLocation = dispatchMombasa;
                   var dispatchLat = '-4.0350145';
                   var dispatchLong = '39.5962225';    

                   console.log(dispatchLocation);
               }
               else if($("#nairobiDistance").val() < $("#mombasaDistance").val())
               {
                   var dispatchLocation = dispatchNairobi;
                   var dispatchLat = '-1.3028618';
                   var dispatchLong = '36.7073099';

                   console.log(dispatchLocation);
               }

               $.ajax({

              data:{
   "action": 'sendyapicall',
   "security": "wc_checkout_params.update_order_review_nonce",
   "command": "request",
   "data": {
       "api_key": "API-Key",
       "api_username": "username",
       "vendor_type": 1,
       "from": {
         "from_name": "dispatchLocation",
         "from_lat": "dispatchLat",
         "from_long": "dispatchLong",
         "from_description": ""
       },
       "to": {
         "to_name": customerLocation,
         "to_lat": cityLat,
         "to_long": cityLng,
         "to_description": ""
       },
       "recepient": {
           "recepient_name": name,
           "recepient_phone": phone,
           "recepient_email": email,
           "recepient_notes": ""
       },
       "delivery_details": {
         "pick_up_date": pickupdate,
         "collect_payment": {
           "status": false,
           "pay_method": 0,
           "amount": amountTotal
         },
                             "return": true,
    "note": " Sample note",
     "note_status": true,
     "request_type": "quote"
   }
   },
   "request_token_id": requestToken
   },
   changeOrigin: true,
   type: 'POST',
   url:ajaxurl,
   success: function(response){
   var responseData = JSON.parse(''+response+'');

   if(responseData.success == false)
   {
       $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
       $('.sendy-errors').html('An error occured. Please refresh the page and try again.');
   }
   else
   {
       console.log('success');

       location.reload();

       console.log(responseData.response.body);
   }
   },
   dataType: 'html',
   error: function(response){
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
   $('.sendy-errors').html('An error occured. Please refresh the page and 
   try again.');
   }
   });




           });
       });
   });
   </script>
   ```
2. I have a text input field with id sendy_location that is using Google's Places API to autocomplete locations. On input, grab the latitude and longitude and pass them to the API.
   Here is the code handling the request.

   ```
   function foo(){
   if ( empty( $_POST['data']['to']["to_lat"] ) || empty( $_POST['data'] 
   ['to']["to_long"] ) ) 
   {
   wp_die( 'You have to select from the list suggested for you' );
   }

      $post_data = wp_unslash( array( 'data' => $_POST['data'] ) );
      $post_data['command'] = wp_unslash( $_POST['command'] );
      $post_data['security'] = wp_unslash( $_POST['security'] );
      $post_data['request_token_id'] = wp_unslash( $_POST['request_token_id'] 
      );

     // var_dump(json_encode( $post_data ));exit;

     $api_url = 'https://apitest.sendyit.com/v1/';

     $response = wp_remote_post( $api_url, array(
     'headers' => array(
   'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
   ),
   'body'    => json_encode( $post_data ),
    ) );

    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) 
    {
    // var_dump(wp_send_json( $response->get_error_message() ));exit;
    echo json_encode(array( 'success' => false, 'response' => $response- 
    >get_eror_message() ));
    exit;
    }
    else 
    {
    $data = json_decode($response["body"]);
    $shippingCost = $data->data->amount;
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['shippingCost'] = $shippingCost;

    // var_dump($shippingCost);exit;

    echo json_encode(array( 'success' => true, 'response' => $response ));

   }
   wp_die();
    }
   ```
3. Here is where I lose everything.I want to pass the shipping cost I stored in the above code that whenever a location is selected the shipping is called by the API and displayed in the checkout page.See the code

   ```
   //make api call to update Shipping cost

   function update_shipping_cost() 
   {
   if ( empty( $_POST['sendy_location']) ) 
   {
       wp_die( 'You have to select from the location dropdown' );
   }

   $shipping_location = $_POST['sendy_location'];
   $cart_total = str_replace(",","",$_POST['cart_total']);
   $cart_total = floatval($cart_total);


   if (empty($shipping_location) ) 
   {
       echo json_encode(array( 'success' => false, 'response' => $response->get_error_message() ));
       exit;
   }
   else 
   {
       //this is where I want to call the shipping cost. currently it's displaying zero
       {
           session_start();
           $_SESSION['shippingCost'] = $shippingCost;
           echo json_encode(array( 'success' => true, 'response' => $response ));


   }

   wp_die();
   }

   /* end */
   ```
4. This function takes the shipping cost returned by the API then I pass it to the function

   ```
   /* shipping cost from sendy */

   function woo_sendy_shipping_cost() 
   {
   @session_start();
   $shippingCost = $_SESSION['shippingCost'];
   WC()->cart->add_fee('Shipping ', $shippingCost);
   }
   ```

Someone please help how I can call the shipping in the above function for it to work.? Thanks in advance.